# PythonTeX: importing/printing all the python files of a folder

Tags: import, pythontex

I'm using Pythontex for my lecture notes. I have a lot of .py files containing classical scripts (simulations of random variable for example), which I use in many files.

My aim is thus the following : I would like to import and typeset .py files and automatically.

According to this proposition (https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/27), I tried the following MWE where a command `\importandtypeset` is defined (I assume that `bernoulli.py` is in `absolutepath_onmymac/`). But I got the following error (all is working fine when I execute the commands `\inputpygments`and `\pyc{from bernoulli import *}` outside `\importandtypeset`).

```
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex3.py", line 2319, in do_pygments
    processed = highlight(content, lexer[c.family], formatter[c.family])
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygments/__init__.py", line 85, in highlight
    return format(lex(code, lexer), formatter, outfile)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygments/__init__.py", line 43, in lex
    return lexer.get_tokens(code)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygments/lexer.py", line 150, in get_tokens
    text, _ = guess_decode(text)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygments/util.py", line 310, in guess_decode
    text = text.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/TeX/texbin/pythontex", line 62, in <module>
    pythontex.main()
  File "/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex3.py", line 2716, in main
    do_multiprocessing(data, temp_data, old_data, engine_dict)
  File "/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex3.py", line 1371, in do_multiprocessing
    result = task.get()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage[rerun=always]{pythontex}

\begin{pythontexcustomcode}[begin]{py}
from pylab import *
import random as rd
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('absolutepath_onmymac/')
def addtopath(p):
    if p and p not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(p)
\end{pythontexcustomcode}

\newcommand{\importandtypeset}[1][.]{%
  \pyc{add_to_path('absolutepath_onmymac/'); from #1 import *; pytex.add_dependencies(os.path.join('absolutepath_onmymac/', '#1.py'))}%
  \inputpygments{python}{absolutepath_onmymac/#1.py}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\inputpygments{python}{absolutepath_onmymac/bernoulli.py}
\pyc{from bernoulli import *}
\py{bernoulli}

\importandtypeset{bernoulli}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might take a look at `\inputpygments` in the PythonTeX documentation.

Comment: Thanks G. Poore. I have red this page carefully (https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/27) and I complete my question.